# How to Run Phoenix in Production Forever

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to run my Phoenix app in production forever, i.e., independently of my terminal process. I saw in Phoenix guides and in a Stackoverflow question that I can use `elixir --detached`, but I'm not being able of using those commands properly. In fact I was able, once, of starting it like that but I tried so many commands that I don'e even know which one make it (also because there's no message to make it clear).
So, using the latest version of Phoenix (1.1) and Elixir (1.1.1), what are the commands to:
1) start the server forever (as a daemon);
2) stop the server without the need of rebooting the server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I never figured out how to run an Elixir/Phoenix app as a daemon using the `--detached` switch myself.  However, I can tell you that building an OTP release with [Exrm](https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm) is the way to go.  It may seem a little intimidating at first, but I promise it is rather easy and after a couple of builds will be virtually mindless for you.  Additionally, if you will invest the time to learn Exrm now, you will not have to refine your production deployments later.

There is a [Phoenix Guide for Exrm Releases](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.13.1/docs/advanced-deployment).  Additionally, I just released an [ExCasts epsiode](https://excasts.com/episodes/exrm-release-for-a-simple-elixir-project) on the subject.  While this episode does not specifically cover a Phoenix release with Exrm, all of the concepts and demonstrations are applicable.  Using Exrm to build OTP releases has many benefits that are covered in the episode, including a script generated with several commands, including but not limited to: `console`, `remote_console` and hot `upgrade`/`downgrade`.  This means you can deploy your application without restarting the application.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thank you Jason. I think I'll follow that road too, but now I need to demo my app to customers and I'm always reconnecting with my remote server to keep it running so this was just for a temporary demo ASAP solution.

Comment: In worst case, use tmux or screen to keep your app running in foreground for your demo.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond Thanks! I'll do.

Comment: I was looking through some of my init scripts and found a usage of the `--detached` switch that seems to be working: `MIX_ENV=prod PORT=4000 /usr/local/bin/elixir --detached -S mix phoenix.server`.  Please note you may need to change the path to your `elixir` executable.

Comment: but, what if the host was rebooted?

Answer (score 1):

Also, see the excellent distillery library. The GitHub is here: https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery

There is also a guide for getting your phoenix application up and running:

https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/phoenix-walkthrough.html#phoenix-walkthrough

Afterwards, you can run the process in the foreground or in the background regarding your preference.